# Linking error in VS2010 with GLew/ GLee/ Unofficial OpenGL SDK

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opengl

I am running Visual Studio 2010 Professional on a Windows 7 64bit laptop (HP Pavilion g6)

Unofficial OpenGL SDK: http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/index.html

Unofficial OpenGL SDK, GLew, & GLee are all up to date, with matching drivers, libs and headers where appropriate

Settings:

```
Preprocessor either over the entire project OR over the main.c file: GLEW_STATIC

Additional Include Directories:
C:/glsdk_0.4.2/glload/include;C:/glsdk_0.4.2/glimg/include;C:/glsdk_0.4.2/glutil/include;C:/glsdk_0.4.2/glmesh/include;C:/glsdk_0.4.2/glm;C:/glsdk_0.4.2/glfw/include;C:/glsdk_0.4.2/freeglut/include;

Additional Library Directories:
C:/glsdk_0.4.2/glload/lib;C:/glsdk_0.4.2/glimg/lib;C:/glsdk_0.4.2/glutil/lib;C:/glsdk_0.4.2/glmesh/lib;C:/glsdk_0.4.2/glfw/library;C:/glsdk_0.4.2/freeglut/lib;

Also tried adding C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.0A/Lib/glew32s.lib (or glew32, glew32mx & glew32mxs);C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.0A/Lib/OpenGL32.lib; in Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependancies

Path Inputs (Changed through Environment Variables. Excluding irrelevant entries):
C:\glsdk_0.4.2\glutil\lib;C:\glsdk_0.4.2\freeglut\lib;C:\glsdk_0.4.2\glfw\library;C:\glsdk_0.4.2\glload\lib;C:\glsdk_0.4.2\glimg\lib;

GLew & GLee lib files are located in:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib
Also tried with them located at:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib

GLew & GLee header files are located in:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\GL
Also tried with them located at:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include\GL
```

Code (other than headers) copied from "OpenGL Distilled", ISBN10 - 0-321-33679-8:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>

    // Uncomment for GLee ( Also comment out glutInit(&argc, argv); )
    //#include <GL\GLee.h>

    // Uncomment for GLew
    /*#include <GL\glew.h>
    #include <GL\wglew.h>
    #include <GL\glut.h>
    #include <GL\glext.h> */

    // Uncomment for all headers in the "Unofficial OpenGL SDK"
    /*#include <glload\gl_all.h>
    #include <GL\glut.h>
    #include <glload\gll.h>
    #include <glimg\glimg.h>
    #include <glutil\glutil.h>
    #include <glmesh\glmesh.h>
    #include <GL\glfw.h>
    #define FREEGLUT_STATIC
    #define _LIB
    #define FREEGLUT_LIB_PRAGMAS 0
    #include <GL\freeglut.h> */


    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        glutInit(&argc, argv);

        // Obtain a buffer identifier from OpenGL
        GLuint bufferID = 0;
        glGenBuffers( 1, &bufferID );

        // Bind the buffer object, OpenGL initially creates it empty.
        glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferID );

        // Define three vertices to draw a right angle triangle.
        const GLfloat vertices[] = [
            0.f, 0.f, 0.f,
            1.f, 0.f, 0.f,
            0.f, 1.f, 0.f };

        // Tell OpenGL to copy data from the 'vertices' pointer into
        // the buffer object
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 3*3*sizeof(GLfloat), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW );
        return 0;
    }
```

Errors:

```
With GLee:
1>gl_crap3.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _GLeeFuncPtr_glBufferData
1>gl_crap3.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _GLeeFuncPtr_glBindBuffer
1>gl_crap3.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _GLeeFuncPtr_glGenBuffers

With the Unofficial OpenGL SDK:
1>gl_crap3.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___gleBufferData
1>gl_crap3.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___gleBindBuffer
1>gl_crap3.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___gleGenBuffers

With GLew:
1>gl_crap3.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewBufferData
1>gl_crap3.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewBindBuffer
1>gl_crap3.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewGenBuffers
```

Comment: Did you actually [use the Premake4 instructions in the SDK](http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/pg_use.html), or are you trying to use it from a VS project of your own making?

Comment: I'm trying to use it in a VS project of my own making. I'm new to OpenGL so I'm trying to learn from the book mentioned above. I only used Premake4 to build the unofficial OpenGL SDK.
The main point I was trying to get across is that I seem to be having exactly the same error with three different library/ header etc settings.
Thanks for your fast reply.

Comment: The reason you're having this problem is because you're not properly linking your executable with the libraries in question. And the reason I asked about the Premake4 thing was that, if you use it to create your projects, it will cover all of that for you. That's why it's there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the SDK, your Visual Studio project should have the following settings (where `sdkbase` is the path to the directory you unzipped and compiled the SDK in).

`C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories`:

```
sdkbase\glload\include;sdkbase\glimg\include;sdkbase\glutil\include;sdkbase\glmesh\include;sdkbase\glm;sdkbase\freeglut\include;sdkbase\glfw\include
```

`Linker->General->Additional Library Directories`:

```
sdkbase\glload\lib;sdkbase\glimg\lib;sdkbase\glutil\lib;sdkbase\glmesh\lib;sdkbase\freeglut\lib;sdkbase\glfw\library
```

`Linker->Input/Additional Dependencies`, for debug builds:

```
glloadD.lib glimgD.lib glutilD.lib glmeshD.lib freeglutD.lib glfwD.lib glu32.lib opengl32.lib gdi32.lib winmm.lib user32.lib
```

For release builds:

```
glload.lib glimg.lib glutil.lib glmesh.lib freeglut.lib glfw.lib glu32.lib opengl32.lib gdi32.lib winmm.lib user32.lib
```

Comment: Thanks! I had foolishly assumed that by stating the library directories that VS knew what to do. Although I am presented with another error, I'll try struggling with it for a while first to see if I can solve it under my own steam. It's a learning curve but I'll get there in the end.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

For people not using the Unofficial OpenGL SDK, I had just run into this problem and, thanks to Nicol Bolas' answer, realized I needed debug libraries for GLEW.

For Visual Studio, I fixed this by replacing `glew32.lib` in my project's debug configuration - at `linker->input/Additional Dependencies` - with `glew32s.lib` (note the **`s`** at the end).

After I did that, everything worked fine.

---

**Note**

While you may be able to initialize GLEW and use **GLEW specific functions** without this fix, as soon as you start making calls to OpenGL you will probably get the error, when building with debug symbols.